# Highlight all numbers on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have to create a progressbar timeline using html and css.Here is the snapshot of output:
[Output current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikkmd.jpg) Currently it is static on 4th number with all previous highlighted. what i want is that when user hover over 3 or 4 or any digit then all previous including current become active, i tried it but not yet success. here is my JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/4ypjufmo/1/
Any Help is highly appreciated

```
    @import "compass/css3";
 li {
     width: 2em;
     height: 2em;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 2em;
     border-radius: 1em;
     background: dodgerblue;
     margin: 0 1em;
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     position: relative;
}
 li::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0.9em;
     left: -4em;
     width: 4em;
     height: 0.2em;
     background: dodgerblue;
     z-index: -1;
}
 li:first-child::before {
     display: none;
}
 .active {
     background: dodgerblue;
}
 .active ~ li {
     background: lightblue;
}
 .active ~ li::before {
     background: lightblue;
}
 body {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     padding: 2em;
}
```

Comment: `.active ~ li` will not select the preceding elements. You can use this hack though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/4813913

Comment: I can't think of an elegant way but you may be able to bruteforce this by giving each number a hover state where it styles the numbers before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses javascript to recognize which item has the `mouseover` and then adds the `active` class to all the ones prior.  Those elements will retain their `active` class until an element is moused over that would cause the active class to be removed.

Note that I also added data attributes to your `<li>` elements to make it a little easier to process them:

```js
let liArray = document.querySelectorAll("li");
liArray.forEach( (element) => 
   element.addEventListener("mouseover",
        function( event ) {   
        doHighlights(+event.target.dataset.step);
    }
));

function doHighlights(inStep) {
   let liArray = document.querySelectorAll("li");
   //console.log(inStep);
   liArray.forEach( (element) => {
      //console.log(+element.dataset.step, inStep);
        if (+element.dataset.step <= inStep) {
        element.classList.add("active");
      } else {
         element.classList.remove("active");
      }
   })
}
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";

li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.9em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: 0.2em;
  background: lightblue;
  z-index: -1;
}

li.active::before {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

li.active {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
body {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     padding: 2em;
}

/*
 .active ~ li {
     background: lightblue;
}
 .active ~ li::before {
     background: lightblue;
}
*/
/*
li:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
*/
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-step="1">1</li>
  <li data-step="2">2</li>
  <li data-step="3">3</li>
  <li data-step="4">4</li>
  <li data-step="5">5</li>
  <li data-step="6">6</li>
  <li data-step="7">7</li>
</ul>
```

(JSFiddle version here: https://jsfiddle.net/79hwa6s4/)

Answer (score 0):

That's easy! All you have to do is remove **active (Class)** from the li tag in *the HTML file* and replace **.active** with **li:hover** *in the CSS file*.

JSFiddle :: https://jsfiddle.net/chbej806/2/

---

### Changes

=> HTML

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

=> CSS

```css
@import "compass/css3";
 li {
     width: 2em;
     height: 2em;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 2em;
     border-radius: 1em;
     background: dodgerblue;
     margin: 0 1em;
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     position: relative;
}
 li::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0.9em;
     left: -4em;
     width: 4em;
     height: 0.2em;
     background: dodgerblue;
     z-index: -1;
}
 li:first-child::before {
     display: none;
}
 li:hover{
     background: dodgerblue;
   cursor: pointer;
}
 li:hover ~ li {
     background: lightblue;
}
 li:hover ~ li::before {
     background: lightblue;
}
 body {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     padding: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
activeIndex = -1;
$("#my-progress li").each(function(index){
  if($(this).hasClass("active"))
    activeIndex = index;
})
$("#my-progress li").mouseover(function(index){
  $("#my-progress li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
})
$("#my-progress li").mouseout(function(index){
  $("#my-progress li").removeClass("active");
  $($("#my-progress li")[activeIndex]).addClass("active");
})
```

```css
li {
     width: 2em;
     height: 2em;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 2em;
     border-radius: 1em;
     background: dodgerblue;
     margin: 0 1em;
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     position: relative;
   cursor:pointer
}
 li::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0.9em;
     left: -4em;
     width: 4em;
     height: 0.2em;
     background: dodgerblue;
     z-index: -1;
}
 li:first-child::before {
     display: none;
}
 .active {
     background: dodgerblue;
}
 .active ~ li {
     background: lightblue;
}
 .active ~ li::before {
     background: lightblue;
}
 body {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="my-progress">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="active">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

if you wants to mouseover item freezes and not recovered to last state ... remove the following code from your script:

```
$("#my-progress li").mouseout(function(index){
  $("#my-progress li").removeClass("active");
  $($("#my-progress li")[activeIndex]).addClass("active");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well why don't you use JavaScript for that, just  for changing which `<li>` element has the class `"active"`, here is how you can do it, and I have written some comments to help you understand the code

```js
// an event delegation for the ul on hover
document.querySelector("ul").onmouseover = function(e) {
  // get the current active <li> element to disactivate it later
  let element = this.querySelector(".active");
  // if the current hovered element is a <li> element
  if(e.target.nodeName === "LI") {
    // just activate the current hovered element
    e.target.classList.add("active");
    // and disactivate the old one only if we found one
    element !== e.target && (element.classList.remove("active"));
  }
}
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";
li {
     width: 2em;
     height: 2em;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 2em;
     border-radius: 1em;
     background: dodgerblue;
     margin: 0 1em;
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     position: relative;
}
 li::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0.9em;
     left: -4em;
     width: 4em;
     height: 0.2em;
     background: dodgerblue;
     z-index: -1;
}
 li:first-child::before {
     display: none;
}
 .active {
     background: dodgerblue;
}
 .active ~ li {
     background: lightblue;
}
 .active ~ li::before {
     background: lightblue;
}
 body {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active">1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```